# jQuery 1.7 .on() event delegation doesn't work with selector on disabled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-delegation

My HTML (not dynamic) looks like this:

```
<select id="domain" class="marketplace">
  <option>United States</option>
  ...
</select>
```

This works:

```
$("#domain").on("change", function() {
  $("#domain").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  /* do ajaxy stuff */
  $("#domain").removeAttr("disabled");
});
$("select.marketplace").on("change", function() { /* do some general stuff */});
```

This does not:

```
$("#domain").on("change", function() {
  $("#domain").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  /* do ajaxy stuff */
  $("#domain").removeAttr("disabled");
});
$(document).on("change", "select.marketplace", function() { /* do some general stuff */});
```

Removing the `$("#domain").attr("disabled", "disabled");` call restores the functionality of the `$(document).on()` delegation, so it appears events do not bubble when an element is disabled, regardless of how the event is triggered (i.e. neither by `.trigger` nor `.triggerHandler` nor by user interaction). However, I do not understand why, as neither handler returns anything or makes any calls to prevent event propagation, and the jQuery documentation makes no mention of the "disabled" attribute having any effect on propagation. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're probably getting an exception in the first handler.  Please show us the complete code.

Comment: ... didn't you *just* ask this?

Comment: It would appear `$("#domain").attr("disabled", "disabled");` in the "specific" handler is the source of the problem. Are events not bubbled for "disabled" elements?

Comment: @minitech Upon further investigation I discovered that my original question was insufficient to describe the failure case (i.e. everyone said "works for me"), so I re-created it to fill in the sufficient context. Was that improper etiquette?

Comment: @kobachi: No, I suppose you deleted it? That's fine then. Normally, though, you can just edit the details into the original question - just for future reference.

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: I've re-framed the question, posted the bits of code that seem to be the culprit. Unfortunately I cannot post the actual code as it's internal to my company.

Comment: I'm guessing @Gothdo really wanted to know the answer to this old question, unfortunately I don't think anyone else really cares about issues that used to be present in jQuery 1.7 and below ?

Comment: @adeneo Actually I had a bit different problem: I wanted to use delegated click event listener on a disabled element and I didn't want to ask new question, because I thought it would be a duplicate. This is not possible in newer jQuery versions too. And I don't think that nobody cares about jQuery 1.7, because for example SE uses jQuery 1.7.1.

Comment: @Gothdo - disabled elements do not fire mouse events, so that's not really possible. However the faulty code in this question now works in jQuery 1.8+

Comment: @adeneo Yes, but in my case the element gets disabled on click by jQuery event listener over which I have no control, and I want to capture the event before the element gets disabled. See [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gothdo/rmyjjfvp/) -- the jQuery event handler doesn't work, but native DOM works.

Comment: @Gothdo - Just use the `mousedown` event

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, I combined it with `mouseup`, and [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/Gothdo/rmyjjfvp/1/) exactly as `click`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to reproduce your problem I created the following snippet (the button Click Me is used to trigger the change event, just to have a full demo):

```js
$(document).on("change", "select.marketplace", function (e) {
  $('#result').append('<p>$(document).on("change", "select.marketplace", function (e) {: This does not work!<p/>');
});
$(function () {
  $("#domain").on("change", function () {
    $("#domain").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    /* do ajaxy stuff */
    //$("#domain").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  $("select.marketplace").on("change", function (e) {
    $('#result').append('<p>$("select.marketplace").on("change", function (e) {: This work!<p/>');
  });
  $('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#domain').trigger('change');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<select id="domain" class="marketplace">
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United States</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I commented the removeAttr disabled on domain change event to reproduce the error.

With jQuery 1.7 the  document on change does not work like you immagine.

Let's now change the document on change with a generic document on and let's filter the event targets:

```js
$(document).on("change", function (e) {
   if ($(e.target).is('select.marketplace')) {
      $('#result').append('<p>$(document).on("change", function (e) {: This works!<p/>');
   }
});
$(function () {
  $("#domain").on("change", function () {
    $("#domain").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    /* do ajaxy stuff */
    //$("#domain").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  $("select.marketplace").on("change", function (e) {
    $('#result').append('<p>$("select.marketplace").on("change", function (e) {: This work!<p/>');
  });
  $('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#domain').trigger('change');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<select id="domain" class="marketplace">
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United States</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now you see a different behaviour, exactly what you are looking for.

Of course it's not the best solution, it's only a way to solve the problem.

I wait for other ideas because my solution is only a workaround.

If you are interested to get more info, you may take a look to the jQuery

`dispatch: function( event ) {`

in the source code [jQuery 1.7](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js) paying attention to "disabled" word.

Comment: Are you saying using .bind for event delegation instead of .on is fixing the problem, only in 1.7? because that syntax of bind doesn't exist. what' you're actually doing is basically identical to `$(document).bind("change",function () {...})` meaning it'l catch all change events, not just the ones from the target elements.

Comment: sorry, i updated the comment. basically, i don't think the code is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/atcwen6m/ changing the second select is incorrectly triggering the event that should only be happening on the first.

Comment: the .delegate() method would be the right alternative, but, it's just going to end up calling .on internally anyway, so it won't fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried namespacing the events like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#domain").on("change.eventOne", function() { /* do some specific stuff */ });
  $(document).on("change.eventTwo", "select.marketplace", function() { /* do some general stuff */ });
});
```

You may also want to try attaching from the body.  I have had better luck with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#domain").on("change.eventOne", function() { /* do some specific stuff */ });
  $('body').on("change.eventTwo", "select.marketplace", function() { /* do some general stuff */ });
});
```

Here is a fiddle of the on event clearly working. Unless I am not understanding what "working" actually means to the OP.

https://jsfiddle.net/szcjszkz/1/

Comment: I have tried attaching from the body without success. As I commented a moment ago, it would appear a call to `$("#domain").attr("disabled", "disabled")` in the `#domain` handler is the source of my trouble, although I do not see anything in the jQuery documentation to explain why.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Post a working code snippet and I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: It would help to know what is not working for you. My interpretation of the original poster's problem was that the $(document).on("change" ... event was not firing.

Comment: Sorry, I removed jQuery version number (1.7) from the question, because I thought it's not relevant, but it turned out it was. This works fine in jQuery 1.8+, but does not with 1.7.

Comment: Yes, but OP is calling `.removeAttr` in an AJAX callback, and in this code it's called immediately.

Comment: @Gothdo Right. I think that this question was very poorly worded. It would be much clearer if you, or the op describe exactly what you are trying to do here. For example, in the op question, he is essentially trying to get a change event to fire on a disabled select. Why disable it then?